# Asymmetric Public Goods Game Reference request

Tags: reference-request, public-goods

I am doing a literature search and wondering if anyone has any good references on something related to the following topic: a one shot public goods game with asymmetric costs and benefits. We can assume a general utility form for all players which is public information, but each player's parameters for the utility function are unique and private information. Furthermore, if the overall contribution does not meet the target, a punishment is shared by all players, not just the players who did not participate.